About the sleep function implementation in xv6
I am taking the os course for mit6.s081, but I seem to misunderstand some concepts in sleep&wakeup. My problem is that after scheduling occurs in sched() in sleep(), p->chan = 0 does not seem necessary. Since the thread corresponding to p->chan is not wakeup at this time (because it can only be wakeup after p->lock is released), won't clearing chan cause lost wakeup?
I tried and failed to understand

Please [edit] your question and add more details about your task description, maybe a link to related documentation and your code as a [mre].

The bit that you're missing is that, by time you reach p->chan = 0;, the wakeup has already happened. The important thing to note is that this thread doesn't have to be the one to release the lock.
sleep calls sched, which in turn (through a context swtch) continues execution in scheduler, right after the point that swtch is called there.
You can see that scheduler has acquired p->lock before it started manipulating this process (and so before the context switch), and it still expects it to be locked after the switch back to the scheduler.
The p->lock will be released a little after the switch back to scheduler, after a few bits of cleanup.
The lock for this process will therefore be unlocked if the scheduler returns execution to a different process, and while it waits for an interrupt if no processes are runnable.
The design of the kernel requires the process lock to be held while the information about the process is being manipulated, including across the context switch to or from the scheduler. However, the receiving context will then release that lock.

thanks so much，I'm thinking much more clearly now
